# Changing vertical and horizontal position for specific label in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to to change vertical and/or horizontal position of a specific label by editing the label properties. For that I put the desired layer into edit modus and clicked on the "change label" button, and marked a specific label. Seems to be straight forward, but it does not as I expect it. Whatever I try in the list box for horizontal positions ("center, left, right") has no effect after clicking the OK button or the "take over" button. It is the same with other settings, except the degree and the text, which I can change.

[image]

The translations might be wrong, but I am working on a German computer.

Did I miss something, or is that a bug?

I use QGIS 3.8 on Manjaro.

Comment: At the begning of the label change process QGIS ask you for a primary key, which is used to store the changes on labeling in the auxilary storage. without this unique ID changes to the labels can not besaved. alternativly you can define your own fields like label_x, label_y, label_rot and set them via the datadefined override property.